# How to automatically determine if a dependency should be an api or an implementation Gradle configuration?

Tags: java, gradle

When migrating to Gradle 7, we have to replace the `compile` configuration by the `implementation` or `api` configurations.

According to the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_recognizing_dependencies):

> An API dependency is one that contains at least one type that is exposed in the library binary interface, often referred to as its ABI (Application Binary Interface). This includes, but is not limited to:
>
> - types used in super classes or interfaces
> - types used in public method parameters, including generic parameter types (where public is something that is visible to compilers. I.e. , public, protected and package private members in the Java world)
> - types used in public fields
> - public annotation types

When migrating large code base with lot of dependencies, it is a tedious task to determine for each dependency if it's an `implementation` or an `api` dependency.

My question is: How to determine automatically if a dependency should be an api or an implementation configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

To automate it, you would need to effectively incorporate the tests from your consumers, assuming there are tests, into the tests of the project. In other words, publish the module locally, modify the consuming project to use the updated dependency, and run their tests. Or write a tests in your project that uses your consumers code would be another approach.

For example, Gradle tests Gradle against select community plugins to ensure they don't break anything: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/smoke-test/src/smokeTest/groovy/org/gradle/smoketests

However, then the questions becomes: who is consuming my project? That itself can be a tedious task.

If you are unsure or don't want to take the time to determine `api` or `implementation`, then use `api` since it is more or less the "same" as `compile`.